# Can I tell whether a block device is in use?

Tags: linux, block-device, device-mapper

Let's assume this is based on device-mapper. How can I tell if a given block device is already in use? (For example, a PV of a currently in use VG, or a encrypted LUKS device that is currently decrypted).

Also - how can I tell whether a given block device comes from device-mapper, or is a physical one?

Comment: Have a look at `/sys/class/block/<device>/holders`

Answer (score 2):

I think `lsblk` will answer these questions for you with a nice display.

```
ls /sys/class/block/*/holders/ | 
awk '/\/sys/ {line=$0; next} ! /^$/ {print line,"\t",$0} /^$/ {line=""}'
```

outputs the same information in a different format.

`dmsetup deps` has some complementary info.